# I want to add two tables in sqlite3 database from python in my tkinter gui

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I want to join two tables in sqlite3 database from python and wanted to display in my tkinter gui. My first table name is users and second table name is data.In users i have three columns f_id,Name.
And in my scond table data there are two columns f_id,Name. I want ti show my users table data in my data and whenever i add a new name in my users i want it to automatically update in my data table
Please Help me and Sorry For my Bad English

```
def createdatabase1(self):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('database1.db')
    self.c = self.conn.cursor()
    self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(cust_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, f_Id INTEGER NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Qty INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(f_Id) REFERENCES users(f_Id) );''')
    self.conn.close()
```

Comment: you need to use an **outer join** among those tables in order to see `user` data even if `data` table of concerned user is not yet populated.

Comment: I believe you need to `commit` these changes using `self.conn.commit()` for it to take effect.

Comment: A DDL statement doesn't need a commit  @CoolCloud

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan oh thanks. I thought all all the changes made to the database needed `commit`. So only DML needs `commit`?